# MVC 6 WebAPI FromServices attribute won't compile

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.mithunvp.com/create-aspnet-mvc-6-web-api-visual-studio-2015/

Which should be up-to-date and should work on rc2

Info:
OS: Win 10 x64 14257
VS: 15 Update 1
DNX: 1.0.0-rc2-16357 clr x86

Error:

```
CS0592  Attribute 'FromServices' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'parameter' declarations.
```

WebAPIController

```
[Route("api")]
public class WebAPIController : Controller
{
    [FromServices]
    IWebAPIRepository WebAPI { get; set; }

    [HttpPost("Authenticate", Name = "Authenticate")] // /api/Authenticate
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromBody] LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (model == null)
            return Ok(new { success = false });

        AuthenticationStatus result = await WebAPI.Authenticate(HttpContext.Authentication, model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe);

        switch (result)
        {
            case AuthenticationStatus.Success:
                return Ok(new { success = true });

            case AuthenticationStatus.LockedOut:
                return Ok(new { success = false, error = "Locked out" });

            case AuthenticationStatus.Failure:
            default:
                return Ok(new { success = false, error = "Invalid login attempt" });
        }
    }
}
```

Which should be fine by that tutorial

WebAPIRepository (interface included in same file, location Models folder)

```
public interface IWebAPIRepository
{
    Task<AuthenticationStatus> Authenticate(AuthenticationManager manager, string email, string password, bool rememberMe);
}

public enum AuthenticationStatus
{
    Success,
    LockedOut,
    Failure
}

public class WebAPIRepository : IWebAPIRepository
{
    public async Task<AuthenticationStatus> Authenticate(AuthenticationManager manager, string email, string password, bool rememberMe)
    {
        // ......

        await manager.SignInAsync("Cookies", new ClaimsPrincipal(id));

        return AuthenticationStatus.Success;
    }
 }
```

And finally Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<IWebAPIRepository, WebAPIRepository>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/forbidden";

            options.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies";
            options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var application = new WebApplicationBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(WebApplicationConfiguration.GetDefault(args))
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        application.Run();
    }
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I figured out solution:

```
IWebAPIRepository WebAPI { get; set; }

public WebAPIController([FromServices] IWebAPIRepository API)
{
        WebAPI = API;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else :))

Comment: FromServices is gone as of RC2, and it won't be available.